# cx_Oracle Statement getting Stuck

Tags: python, sql, oracle, cx-oracle

While using cx_Oracle(Python), the code goes into waiting when the the following statement is executed:

```
some_connection.execute(some_sql)
```

What could be the reason?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing this "some_sql"". Most likely the reason is "some error in some_sql".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing the actual SQL in question it is hard to know for sure. Some possible answers include:

1) the SQL actually takes a long time to execute (and you just have to be patient)

2) the SQL is blocked by another transaction (and that transaction needs to be committed or rolled back first)

You can find out by examining the contents of dba_locks, specifically looking at the blocking_others column. You can also attempt to issue the same SQL in SQL*Plus and see if it exhibits the same behaviour.

Comment: It was because a previous transaction was not  committed.

Comment: Is there a way to tell cx_Oracle to not wait forever?

Comment: You can use the callTimeout feature available with Oracle Client 18.1 and cx_Oracle 7.

Comment: The callTimeout feature seems to be helping, thanks. It also helped to play with sqlnet.ora settings.